Create a widget and capture it as an image while Flutter app is not running
In my flutter app, we have a use case where I need to generate a screenshot of a particular widget (a section on a screen) and save it as an image.
I have seen that there is the screenshot package and a few others that can be used to achieve this while the user is actively using the app.
However, the requirement is that I want to do this operation while the app is

not running
in the background
running, but the particular feature is not open

So, I have to create the widget, and capture the screenshot in a non-ui environment; Is it possible to achieve that? How?
Edit:
I need to do this operation in a top-level function (firebaseBackgroundMessageHandler to be precise). When a data notification is received, I want to generate the image of a widget with new data.
Here's what I tried;
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  appLog(
      "Background message: ${message.messageId} ${message.notification?.title} ${message.notification?.body} ${message.data}");

  print('creating image...');
  final ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  Screenshot(
    controller: screenshotController,
    child: Container(
      height: 128,
      width: 128,
      color: Colors.brown,
      child: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Sample',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List? image) {
    print(image);
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
}

But since the screenshot package is designed to work within the widget tree, it doesn't work, giving an error:
